# How to get the column names, column types and constraints using Oracle.jl?

Tags: oracle, julia

table structure and data:

```
SQL> desc ava.subjects;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                    NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 SUBJECT                        VARCHAR2(50)

SQL> select * from ava.subjects;

    ID SUBJECT
---------- --------------------------------------------------
     1 tamil
     2 english
     3 mathematics
     4 science
     5 social science
```

julia script to get the column names:

```
import Oracle

global const dbHost = "localhost";
global const dbClientType = "thin";
global const dbName = "xe";
global const dbPort = "1521";
global const dbUserName = "ava";
global const dbUserPassword = "ava";
global const conn_str="//"*dbHost*":"*dbPort*"/"*dbName;


function prepare_connection()
global conn = Oracle.Connection(dbUserName, dbUserPassword, conn_str);
end

function close_connection()
Oracle.close(conn);
end

global select_query = "SELECT * FROM ava.subjects"

function list_subjects()
select_stmt = Oracle.Stmt(conn, select_query)
Oracle.query(select_stmt) do cursor
    println(names(cursor))
    end
end


prepare_connection()

list_subjects()

close_connection()
```

Error, as follows:

```
julia> include("/root/columns.jl")
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching names(::Oracle.Cursor)
Closest candidates are:
  names(::Module; all, imported) at reflection.jl:98
Stacktrace:
 [1] (::var"#29#30")(::Oracle.Cursor) at /root/columns.jl:25
 [2] query(::var"#29#30", ::Oracle.Stmt{Oracle.ORA_STMT_TYPE_SELECT}; exec_mode::Oracle.OraExecMode) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/Oracle/6WKJK/src/cursor.jl:74
 [3] query(::Function, ::Oracle.Stmt{Oracle.ORA_STMT_TYPE_SELECT}) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/Oracle/6WKJK/src/cursor.jl:73
 [4] list_persons() at /root/columns.jl:24
 [5] top-level scope at /root/columns.jl:32
 [6] include(::String) at ./client.jl:439
 [7] top-level scope at REPL[1]:1
 [8] eval(::Module, ::Any) at ./boot.jl:331
 [9] eval_user_input(::Any, ::REPL.REPLBackend) at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/REPL/src/REPL.jl:86
 [10] run_backend(::REPL.REPLBackend) at /opt/julia/julia-1.4.1/share/julia/stdlib/v1.4/packages/Revise/OgnOk/src/packagedef.jl:1233
 [11] top-level scope at REPL[1]:0
in expression starting at /root/columns.jl:32
```

Please guide me in getting column names, column types and constraints using Oracle.jl

Comment: If you want help executing a SQL statement in Julia, the best place to ask is https://github.com/felipenoris/Oracle.jl/issues  If you want to find what SQL statements to use to get constraints etc, then do some searching: there are lots of posts and examples.